# boost::any how to check for a null/undefined value

Tags: c++, boost, types, null, boost-any

I have a boost::any object, and I would like to check its type.

```
typedef boost::any Value;

Value a = 12;

if(a.type() == typeid(int)) {
    std::cout << boost::any_cast<int>(a) << std::endl;
}
```

This is easy enough when the type is defined, however how would I achieve a the same result when the type is not defined (i.e. because its value has not been set yet).

```
Value b;

if(b is undefined) {
   std::cout << "b is not defined" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: std::any has has_value() method, i expect that boost has the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`boost::any::empty`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/any.html#idp9449872-bb) will return `true` if there is no value.

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2t6EduM3ff4RHh9h)

```
#include "boost/any.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::any a = 42;
    if (!a.empty())
        std::cout << "a has a value\n";

    boost::any b;
    if (b.empty())
        std::cout << "b does not have a value\n";
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `boost::any::type` like you did in the first example and, if there's no value, it will return `typeid(void)`:

#### [Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MprBtMG1uBtJd6sW)

```
boost::any a = 42;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a.type() == typeid(int)) << std::endl; // true

boost::any b;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << (b.type() == typeid(void)) << std::endl; // true
```